# How to make a Model and View that saves the data in DB for a guest user (not registered in User auth.model)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

IS it possible to save the Form data from a `Guest` / `Visitor` in the DB?

MY Idea is to display a form where a User is presented with the questions. The answers are unique for each user to I want to map the answers to the Users using a Foreign Key. Problem is that when I want to map it using `ForeignKey` it says that the answers come from a Null User. I ant my visiting users to access the website also.

**I have saved the Data in sessions and then used it** 
`I Do not want to use that approach`

Is there any way so that my users can access the website without saving the data in the website. Anyways, the flow of code deletes the answers data from DB once the work is done.

It is not about getting the work done but exploring and getting knowledge.

I can not do

```
class AnsModel(model.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ans=models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

What would be the `Model` and `View` for this?

Comment: you can add `null=True` in your foreignkey.

Comment: So how would I map my guest User to DB? and how would I fetch Data again to process it?